# Adjust Axis Scales of Histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R studio, I have a group of histograms with three columns and two rows for each 'type' x, y, z, -x, -y, and -z. Currently, the scales fit to each individual graph type. The problem is that some types have a max bin of say 30, where others have a max bin of 5, so you could not visually compare the graphs together.

What I need is to match the histogram scales of the y(count) and x axis(load) for 'type' x, y, -x and -y so they can be equally comparable. I would also like to match the z and -z 'type' scales.

Is this possible?

I might also be happy if I could get all 6 axis scales be the same.

My guess is somehow to find the each types max bin value and then find the max bin value between the all the types maxes and use that to set the y axis. Then for the x scale, do the same but just find the max 'value' for each type.

This is the code I have that works so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Sample data set
 max_values <- data.frame(
   type = c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","z","z","z","z","z","-x","-x","-x","-x","-y","-y","-y","-y","-z","-z","-z","-z","-z"),
   values = c(0.5,1,2,0.3,1,2,3,4,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,2,5,5.1,6,4.9,3,10,9.5,9.1,9,9.7,8)
 )


# create a list of type values
 type_list <- c("x", "y", "z", "-x", "-y", "-z")
 
 # create an empty list to store the plots
 plot_list <- list()
 
 # loop through the type values and create a plot for each type
 for (i in type_list) {
   plot_data <- max_values %>% filter(type == i, scenario == 1)
   if(nrow(plot_data) > 0) {  # add a check to make sure the data is not empty
     plot <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(value)) +     
       geom_histogram(colour= 1, fill = "white", binwidth=0.5) +
       ggtitle(paste("Histogram |", toupper(i), "Max values | Scenario 1")) +
       xlab("Load (N) [Bin top 0.5]") +
       ylab("Count (@500 samples per sec)")
     
     # add the plot to the plot_list
     plot_list[[i]] <- plot
   }
 }
 
 # display the plots
 gridExtra::grid.arrange(
   plot_list[["x"]],
   plot_list[["y"]],
   plot_list[["z"]],
   plot_list[["-x"]],
   plot_list[["-y"]],
   plot_list[["-z"]],
   ncol = 3
 )
```

Thanks!

I tried adding things in the loop, out side of the loop, lots of stuff nothing seemed to work correctly

here is something I tried that almost worked, but not quite

```
# loop through the type values and create a plot for each type
for (i in type_list) {
  plot_data <- max_values %>% 
    filter(type == i, scenario == 1)
  
  if(nrow(plot_data) > 0 && !all(is.na(plot_data$value))) { # check for non-missing values
    # create bins of width 0.5 based on the values in the `value` column
    plot_data$binwidth <- cut(plot_data$value, breaks = seq(0, max(plot_data$value), by = 0.5), include.lowest = TRUE)
    
    # add a group column based on the bin width
    plot_data$group <- as.factor(match(plot_data$binwidth, unique(plot_data$binwidth)))
    
    # get the max bin width
    max_binwidth <- max(as.numeric(plot_data$binwidth))
    
    # create the plot
    plot <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(value)) +     
      geom_histogram(colour=1, fill="white", binwidth=0.5) +
      ggtitle(paste("Histogram |", toupper(i), "Max values | Scenario 1")) +
      xlab("Load (N) [Bin top 0.5]") +
      ylab("Count (@500 samples per sec)") +
      facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free_y") +  # group the histograms by the bin width
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max_binwidth), expand = c(0,0)) +  # set the x axis limits
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), expand = c(0,0))  # set the y axis limits
    
    # add the plot to the plot_list
    plot_list[[i]] <- plot
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it "almost worked but not quite"?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach to achieve your desired result would be to simply use faceting instead of creating individual plots. Doing you will automatically get identical scales for each of your types:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

max_values <- data.frame(
  type = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "-x", "-x", "-x", "-x", "-y", "-y", "-y", "-y", "-z", "-z", "-z"),
  value = c(0.5, 1, 2, 0.3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 2, 5, 5.1, 6, 4.9, 3, 10, 9.5, 9.1, 9, 9.7, 8),
  scenario = 1
)

type_list <- c("x", "y", "z", "-x", "-y", "-z")

max_values$type <- factor(max_values$type, type_list)

# Facetting
ggplot(max_values, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(colour = 1, fill = "white", binwidth = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~type, labeller = as_labeller(function(x) paste("Histogram |", toupper(x), "Max values | Scenario 1"))) +
  xlab("Load (N) [Bin top 0.5]") +
  ylab("Count (@500 samples per sec)")
```

[image]

To achieve the same result with individual plots requires some more effort. Basically you were on the right track in computing the x and y ranges. However, in case of `geom_histogram` getting the ranges requires to take account of the binning when computing the ranges and when setting the limits.

Note: Instead of using a `for` loop I would suggest to use `lapply` which in general works better with `ggplot2`. To this end I also use a custom plotting function. Additionally I switched to `patchwork` to glue the plots.

```r
# Plot Function with fixed limits
plot_fun <- function(i, binwidth = .5) {
  # Take account of the binning
  xlim <- range(plyr::round_any(max_values$value, binwidth / 2, floor))
  
  ylim <- cut_width(max_values$value, width = binwidth) |> 
    table(max_values$type) |> 
    range()
  
  plot_data <- max_values %>% filter(type == i, scenario == 1)

  ggplot(plot_data, aes(value)) +
    geom_histogram(colour = 1, fill = "white", binwidth = binwidth) +
    # Take account of the binning
    scale_x_continuous(limits = xlim + binwidth / 2 * c(-1, 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = ylim) +
    labs(
      title = paste("Histogram |", toupper(i), "Max values | Scenario 1"),
      x = "Load (N) [Bin top 0.5]",
      y = "Count (@500 samples per sec)"
    )
}

plot_list <- lapply(type_list, plot_fun)

wrap_plots(plot_list, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: both these worked out great! 

One clarification, I adjusted the sample here:

 max_values <- data.frame(
   type = c("x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y",
            "z","z","z","z","z","z",
            "-x","-x","-x","-x","-y","-y","-y","-y","-z","-z","-z","-z","-z"),
   values = c(0.5,1,2,0.3,1,2,3,4,
              0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1,
              2,5,5.1,6,4.9,3,10,9.5,9.1,9,9.7,8)
 )

Lets say my z had a count of 5 in a bin and I wanted my '-z' an 'z' y-axis scales to match each other and matching my 'x, y, -x, and -y' y-axis scales to each other.